# How do I recognise an empty query parameter in python?

Tags: python, cgi

I need to be able to distinguish between having an empty string in a query parameter and not having that parameter. The following code:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
foo = form.getfirst('foo')
```

Both http://example.com?foo and http://example.com result in foo being None. I'd like to have in the first case foo being an empty string and only in the second cache None. What do I have to do to distinguish between both caches.

p.s. http://example.com?foo=bar results in foo being bar as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265825/getting-empty-form-fields-with-python-cgi-stdlib) is what you are searching for.

Passing keep_blank_value=1 to your FieldStorage constructor could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the presence of the `foo` key in the form using the `in` operator:

```py
foo = form.getfirst('foo', '') if 'foo' in form else None
```

Comment: Tried that, but in both cases the directory is empty, so in both cases 'foo' in form will be False